# How to add whitespaces in range( 0,4) to string in C

Tags: c, printf, whitespace

I am looking for a way to create this output in C:

```
Hello World!
   Hello World!
      Hello World!
          Hello World!
```

whereas with each time the "Hello World!" is being printed, another " " is being added to the string. Printing the string is not the problem - but I am not sure how I can work with the space. Below is my current code.

An Idea for the implementation of the " " was to add  " " times `i`. In theory this should add the correct number of whitespace to the start of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("\nHello World!");
    }

    //idea: spaces = " " * i 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have been a member here for a while, may I recommend to take the very enlightening [tour]?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested loop to print the desired number of blanks.
Also moving the output of newline to the end is a widely applied habit and in this case makes things easier.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("Hello World!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Moving the newline is important, because it changes the output and with the newline at the start your basically applicable idea of `" "` times `i` would not result in the desired output.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish you a happy new year!

Comment: :-) My pleasure and same to you.

Answer (score 2):

From my look at the characters in `Hello World!` they need to be offset from the right by 3-additional characters with each iteration. So if you start with a defined shift of `3` and then loop `0 - 4`, you can use a variable field-width modifier at the front of your `printf` string to produce the offset, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHIFT  3       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NLINES 4

int main (void) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NLINES; i++)                  /* loop for NLINES iterations */
        printf ("%*sHello World!\n", i * SHIFT, "");  /* increase by multiples of shift */
}
```

The format is created by the format string `"%*sHello World!\n"` where `"%*s"` expects an integer argument for the field-width where the `'*'` in `"%*s"` will be replaced with the integer field-width provided as the result of `i * shift` providing an offset that progresses by multiples of 3.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hwshift
Hello World!
   Hello World!
      Hello World!
         Hello World!
```

Above that seems to capture the wanted format.Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Chuckling, guilty as charged. 2021 is looking up once we solve the deranged cheeto problem.... (and if we avoid bankruptcy presuming the courts are not shut down for 6 months of 2021 `:)` Now that pesky magic number is gone...

Answer (score 1):

You could specify a string with a dynamic field width in the format string to indent the beginning of each line of output:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%*sHello World!\n", i, "");
}
```

Here the `%*s` means that the first argument to `printf()` is the field width for the next field, which is an empty string in this case.

Output:

```
Hello World!
 Hello World!
  Hello World!
   Hello World!
```

You can increase the indent by multiplication:

```
int indent=2;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%*sHello World!\n", i * indent, "");
}
```

outputs:

```
Hello World!
  Hello World!
    Hello World!
      Hello World!
```